# Excluding standalone apostrophes from the text

Tags: java, regex

I need to exclude from text all symbols, except letters, spaces and standalone apostrophes (like: " ' " or "this ' is"), but leave apostrophes as is if they are part of the word (like: "word'" or "that's" or "'word").
I tried String `.replaceAll("[^a-z'\\s]","")` method, and it seems I need to add there something like `[^([a-z]*'[a-z]+|[a-z]+'[a-z]*)]`, but I can't make complete expression and it seems second part of expression is not valid.

Thanks for help!

Comment: A bit of a stretch, and most likely there is a better pattern, but maybe: `[^[a-zA-Z ']|(?<![a-zA-Z])'(?![a-zA-Z])`

Comment: tryied it, but standalone " ' " is still included

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, I thought you wanted to remove standalone apostropes? And leave the ones that belong to a word.

Comment: Try `.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s']|\\B'|'\\B","")`

Comment: JvdV, correct, but your option didn't remove standalone " ' ";
@WiktorStribiżew, this option filters words like " word' " also

Comment: Oh, looks like you want `.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s']|(?<!\\S)'(?!\\S)","")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```java
s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s']|(?<!\\S)'(?!\\S)","")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qb05qY/1/). Details:

- `[^a-zA-Z\s']` - any char but an ASCII letter, whitespace and single quotation mark
- `|` - or
- `(?<!\S)'(?!\S)` - a `'` not preceded nor followed with a non-whitespace char.

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/pLNStG):

```java
String s = " ' this ' is word' that's 'word";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s']|(?<!\\S)'(?!\\S)",""));
// =>   this  is word' that's 'word
```

Comment: It didn't work as expected, but I googled for positive/negative lookbehinds and found a valid solution with that code: `"(?<=[\\s'])'(?=[\\s'])"`
Thanks!

Comment: @ko4evneg Glad you finally came up with the pattern requirements :)